# How to hide error code in the error message in JWPlayer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer

I have a React code as shown below which renders player. In the code below, I am using ReactJWPlayer component with their props. In order to configure [intl.{lang}.errors](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-configuration-reference#intllangerrors-object), I have used customProps option exposed by [react-jw-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jw-player)

```
const ReactJWPlayerContainer = props => {
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [errorNode, setErrorNode] = useState(null);
 
    const player = ()=> {
            return (
                <ReactJWPlayer
                    playlist={[props.playlist]}
                    customProps={{
                        intl: {
                          en: {
                            errors: {
                              badConnection: "This video cannot be played because of a problem with your internet connection.",
                              cantLoadPlayer: "Sorry, the video player failed to load.",
                            },
                          },
                          fr: {
                            errors: {
                              badConnection: "This video cannot be played because of a problem with your internet connection.",
                              cantLoadPlayer: "Sorry, the video player failed to load.",
                            },
                          },
                        },
                      }}  
                />
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            {props.playlist && player()}
        </>
    )

}
```

The above code successfully displays custom error message with the respective error code in case if the player fails to load.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the React code above so that it successfully hides the error code. In the screenshot below, I want to hide the line  `(Error Code: 232011)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass props.playlist as a variable but you're passing as an array item.

Change this code playlist={[props.playlist]} to playlist={props.playlist}

I'm assuming that props.playlist is an array like this example:

https://github.com/micnews/react-jw-player#playing-a-custom-playlist